# Is there a way to capture the parameter types of a function definition with a macro?

Tags: rust, macros

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to wrap a function in a proc_macro like this:

```
native_function! {
    fn sum(x:i32, y:i32) -> i32 {
        x+y
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find what I need to put in this function:

```
#[proc_macro]
pub fn native_function(item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    ...
}
```

Inside the function above, I need to be able to capture the types of the parameters defined in the function; in this case - "i32"

I've tried all sorts of ways to do this, but currently I'm stumped. I'm trying to avoid using a derive macro since I don't want to have to complete and instantiate a struct. I don't even need a full solution, but if someone can point me to the function/object/library I need to be using to that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`syn`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/) is the cannonical parsing library for proc macros.

Using it this is easy:

```rust
let f = syn::parse_macro_input!(item as syn::ItemFn);

let types: Vec<syn::Type> = f
    .sig
    .inputs
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(|arg| match arg {
        syn::FnArg::Receiver(_) => None,
        syn::FnArg::Typed(syn::PatType { ty, .. }) => Some(*ty),
    })
    .collect();
```

By the way, your macro can be [an attribute macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#attribute-macros).

If you want to know whethere the type is a some known type, note first that you can never be sure; that is because macros operate without type information, and code like `struct i32;` is legal and will shadow the primitive `i32` type.

If you've accepted this limitation, what you actually want is to compare it to a [path type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#paths-in-types). Path types are represented by the [`Path`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/enum.Type.html#variant.Path) variant of `syn::Type`. It has `qself`, which is the `T` in `<T as Trait>::AssociatedType` and `None` in a simple path (not fully-qualified, just `A::B::C`), and `path`, which is the `Trait::AssociatedType` or `A::B::C`. Paths are complex; they can contain generics, for example, but if all you want is to check if this is one-segment type of simple identifier like `i32`, `syn` has got you covered: just use [`Path::is_ident()`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.Path.html#method.is_ident). So:

```rust
let is_i32 = match ty {
    syn::Type::Path(ty) => ty.path.is_ident("i32"),
    _ => false,
}
```

If you want to compare against a more complex type, you will have to walk and match segment-by-segment.

Comment: Thanks for this. How do I extract the value from syn::Type to get to the i32 part?

Comment: @JackP What do you mean by "the i32 part"? [`syn::Type`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/enum.Type.html) is an enum, containing a structural view of a Rust type. What to do with it depends on your needs. You can, for example, `match` it to handle different types. If all you want is a flat stream of tokens, you can call [`to_token_stream()`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/enum.Type.html#method.to_token_stream) on it.

Comment: What I need is simply a way to know that the parameters are i32 and not, say, f32, or i64 .. I get that I can expand to another token stream, but I still need to extract the raw type of the parameter. It's not clear to me how I get that from the syn::Type members ..

Comment: Do you want to confirm it's a specific type, say `i32`?

Comment: Yes .. I'd like to match against it and check if it's a i32 or i64 or whatever other datatype. In other words, I need to know what dataype the parameters were declared as

Comment: But what do you mean by "know"? Say it was of type `MyStruct`. What does it say to you? It only makes sense if you want to compare it to a list of predefined types.

Comment: Comparing against predefined types would be fine. I just can't figure out how to extract the token I'd need to use to compare against those predefined types